# How to convert punjabi unicode to English Text?

Tags: unicode

I have records saved in SQL SERVER database in form of punjabi unicode. Now i want to convert these punjabi unicode to English Text. Is there any utility which can help me? Please reply if anyone have solution paid/free. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a broad question. An example (input -> output) of what you hope to achieve would be very helpful.

Comment: "Punjabi Unicode" ? This question is way too broad.

Answer (score 1):

The question is nonsensical -- in the sense that it makes no sense.

Unicode is not a *language*. It merely provides a mapping from characters (more precisely, *glyphs*) to a binary code, in such a way that text in a font using Punjabi characters will stay that way when another font is applied. There is no "English" Unicode, and no "Punjabi" Unicode either.

You can only 'translate' from Punjabi to English using translating software. (Given the current state of automatic translation software, you are better off with a human who is fluent in both languages.)

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to change Punjabi Unicode converted into English Text as example

ਨਿੱਕੀ ਕਹਾਣੀ (unicode)
in`kI khwxI (Converted into Gurmukhi Lipi, shows as English ! When you change its font into GurmukhiLipi it shows in punjabi)

You can check my website, previously in UNICODE and now in GURBANI LIPI (I have installed a plugin to convert English Letters as Punjabi)